Do you reuse the same Kanban cards when handing off a requirement for implementation?
I'm thinking of creating some work item types where the Kanban cards represent a high-level software requirement, a low-level software requirement, and another for system level requirements. When the requirement is defined and ready to go for further design and coding, does this card get assigned to someone for implementation where it then moves through coding, testing, etc.? Or do developers work with new Kanban cards specific for the development workflows?
For example, a requirement with a card "Display Speed" moves through waiting, analysis, specification, done.
A developer now sees that a requirement is ready for implementation and is assigned the "REQ Display Speed" card, which then goes through, design, coding, testing.
Or is it that a new card, "DEV implement Display Speed", is assigned and goes through design, coding, testing?
In short, does the card go through the whole lifecycle, or does it stop at the end of that particular workflow, and a new one is created for the downstream workflow?

After re-reading your question a few times, I think the fact that you're looking at this in terms of upstream and downstream instead of continuous flow or integrated processes is a "process implementation smell." Without intending any criticism, I think you may have a more foundational problem with your Kanban process, and the question about how to handle cards for your use case is just symptomatic of that. It's certainly worth considering whether you've properly represented the full system or captured the complete set of value streams for your present implementation.

TL;DR
Take a step back first. In Kanban, whether a card moves between columns, swimlanes, or even boards is really a side-effective of how work flows. It's all about how the system's queues and value streams are optimized (or sometimes strategically de-optimized) to ensure smooth and continuous flow at the systems level. That is where you should start, rather than treating the transfer of cards between boards, duplication of cards, or rewriting of cards as necessities for improving your Kanban implementation.
Questioning the Framing Assumptions
Your question has a lot of implied assumptions. For example, does everyone who touches this card know what "Display Speed" is about? If it's part of a routine workflow, maybe that's all that's needed. However, if it's a new feature or set of tasks then such a high-level summary may be insufficient to communicate the value each touch in the flow needs to add.
Additionally, the way the question is phrased strongly implies that you may have multiple workflows that each require their own board. For example, if business analysts aren't working with your developers, and each part of the value stream is just tossing specifications or work items "over the wall" to other teams, then you probably don't have a single Kanban or a unified flow. In such cases, cards may need to be in stateful buckets when pending other queues. Simply flowing from one end of the board to the other is a more ideal state, but there are certainly value streams where that isn't possible.
Steps to Take Regardless of Framing
Rather than addressing what is potentially an X/Y problem, I'd suggest the following steps.

Kanban is based on working agreements, so ask the people involved where (or even if) the current process is lacking from their perspectives.
Use a systems-thinking view of the entire process to identify where value-adding steps intersect, and where the bottlenecks are.
Each bottleneck is essentially a queue, so you may need to add steps, buckets, or additional boards to your Kanban to properly account for them.
Track and continuously refine that process until everyone is happy.

That's definitely an oversimplification, but still captures the high-level steps that you'll need to address. Ultimately, it's not about whether a card moves between columns, swimlanes, or even boards; it's all about how queues and value streams are optimized (or sometimes strategically de-optimized) to ensure smooth and continuous flow at the systems level.

I had never heard of "X/Y problem" before until I read this post and now I'm glad I read up on it because it's helping me understand the current problem by looking at the workflow. When I look at from a work type perspective, I have system, high-level, and low-level requirements. I recently experienced a bottle neck just on the high-level requirements, because we waited for a complete set before reviewing. Perhaps I could have had a single high-level requirement completed, reviewed, and then moved on to low-level requirements, while I continued with the next high-level requirement.

You can have it both ways.
A card represents work. As work moves from one stage to another, the card follows along to represent the new state. One card. You don’t need two.
However, if there are boundaries that some tool imposes for example, maybe the business owners have their own Kanban tool where they refine the requirements, while the development team uses a different Kanban board to track their work, you could create a second card and refer there in some way to the first card. You still represent the same work, but in different places of the organization.
It really depends on your setup. If you have the option to move the same card through the entire value stream, that is usually preferable than to duplicate the same piece of information.

If I take a systems approach to it, then I could take one system requirement and move it through the stages of high-level and low-level requirements and finally into code. Because things are tied together through traceability, one has the whole context. In the end, that system requirement is what needs to be implemented. Everything else is adding value and refinement to the design and code, but it's all directed at that system requirement.

I think my problem was I was confusing a work item type with the deliverables or artifacts generated at each stage. I suppose this is like a typical purchase order. On a board, we wouldn't see a bunch of cards showing the individual items of the purchase and their state, but instead would see that the purchase order itself is in for example in waiting, fulfillment, or shipped.
